# How to print numbers in hex with leading zero

Tags: ruby, hex, hexdump, leading-zero

Is there a better method to display a number in hex with leading `0`? I tried:

```
i.to_s(16)
```

but

```
2.to_s(16) #=> "2"
```

where I expect `"02"`. I tried the print format:

```
"%02x" % i
```

which works for `2`, but

```
"%02x" % 256 #=> "100"
```

where I want `"0100"`. So I came up with this:

```
class Integer
  def to_hex_string
    ("%0x" % self).size % 2 == 0 ? "%0x" % self : "%0#{("%0x" % self).size+1}x" % self
  end
end
```

It works:

```
2.to_hex_string #=> "02"
256.to_hex_string #=> "0100"
```

It works also with class `Bignumber`, but it looks strange that such an easy request needs a trick like this. Any better idea?

Comment: If you just want to put a zero in front of the number, try `"0#{i.to_s(16)}"` or `"0%x" % i`. But this usually denotes an octal number. The common hex prefix is `0x` which can be printed using `"%#x" % i`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it seems that to_s(16) is bugged with BigNumber

Answer (score 3):

Use `"%.2x"`, where 2 is the amount of digits you want.

```rb
"%.2x" % 0   # => "00"
"%.2x" % 15  # => "0f"
"%.2x" % 255 # => "ff"
```

Answer (score 2):

for 2-digit hex values this works:

```
def to_hex(int)
  int < 16 ? '0' + int.to_s(16) : int.to_s(16)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it bugs:

Let's try this:

```
class Integer
  def to_hex_string
     "0#{to_s(16)}"
  end
end

class BigNumber
  def to_hex_string
    "0#{to_s(16)}"
  end
end

class String
  def to_hex_string
    self.unpack('H*').first
  end

  def to_bytes_string
    unless self.size % 2 == 0
      raise "Can't translate a string unless it has an even number of digits"
    end
    raise "Can't translate non-hex characters" if self =~ /[^0-9A-Fa-f]/
    [self].pack('H*')
  end

  def to_bignum
    self.bytes.inject { |a,b| (a << 8) + b }
  end
end

p a="ff"*192 # => "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"

p bytestring=a.to_bytes_string # => "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"

p bytestring.to_hex_string # => "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"

p biga=a.to_bytes_string.to_bignum # => 2410312426921032588580116606028314112912093247945688951359675039065257391591803200669085024107346049663448766280888004787862416978794958324969612987890774651455213339381625224770782077917681499676845543137387820057597345857904599109461387122099507964997815641342300677629473355281617428411794163967785870370368969109221591943054232011562758450080579587850900993714892283476646631181515063804873375182260506246992837898705971012525843324401232986857004760339316735
```

And the BUG is here:

```
p biga.to_hex_string # => "0ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
```

Where does this 0 come from????

What is even more strange is my complicated solution is working:

```
p ("%0x" % biga).size % 2 == 0 ? "%0x" % biga : "%0#{("%0x" % biga).size+1}x" % biga # => "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
```

Maybe a bug in "0#{to_s(16)}"?

Answer (score 0):

This was the first hit on Google when I was just trying to solve this.  I had to find a couple of other posts to finish up my solution but I think this is clean.

```
class Fixnum
  def to_hex(bits)
    rjust = (bits/4 + (bits.modulo(4)==0 ? 0 : 1))
    "0x" + self.to_s(16).rjust(rjust, "0")
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

You are making this way too complicated. If you want to print an integer in hexadecimal with a leading zero, then it is just

```
class Integer
  def to_hex_string
    "0#{to_s(16)}"
  end
end

2.to_hex_string   # => 02
256.to_hex_string # => 0100
```

Comment: sure it is a lot easier like this! Thanks!

Comment: But it seems to bug for bignumber. If you try for exemple with "ff"*192, if will bug to convert to bignum and back to hex

Comment: This answer is wrong IMHO: It always puts a 0 in front. I think the OP wants a 0 in front in case of `2.to_hex_string` = 02 but a `200.to_hex_string` should probably return "c8" not "0c8" i.e. the leading 0 should only be added on odd string length.